# How to test Go code with filepaths defined as constants

Tags: unit-testing, go, constants

I'm writing tests for a project of mine, which involves fixed filepaths and base URLs. To me, the most logic way to define them is by means of public/private constants in a relevant module, but that prevents good testing practices. How can I work around this?

I searched for a possible solution and found that I can define two constructors for a struct in need of a path: one which defines the default path, and another that accepts a custom path

```
func Construct(param string) MyStruct {
    return MyStruct {Param: param, Path: "/default/path"}
}

func ConstructWithPath(param, path string) MyStruct {
    return MyStruct {Param: param, Path: path}
}
```

This is pretty ugly to me and it's a solution tailored exclusively for tests since the paths I'm considering are fixed and known.

Comment: If tests are important to you, there should be no problem with a solution tailored exclusively for tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and is commonly used for testing. There's nothing particularly ugly about making your code more testable.

An alternative would be to define the paths as `var`s in the package (make them private - tests live in the same package) and the tests could set these vars to something before doing the test.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine. It's a common and recommended practice to design your code and interfaces to be testable.
I would slightly modify your solution to prevent duplication-

```
func Construct(param string) MyStruct {
    return ConstructWithPath(param, "/default/path")
}

func ConstructWithPath(param, path string) MyStruct {
    return MyStruct {Param: param, Path: path}
}
```

You need not export ConstructWithPath if you don't want anyone outside this package using it.